# How to avoid multi cursor on wrapped lines in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have turned on Word Wrap in VSCode, so that long lines are wrapped at certain window widths.

If I want to comment out some code or text, I usually just move the cursor to the beginning of the first line of the block of code, use ctrl+shift+down to add cursors, and type the `//` or `#` etc..

The problem with Word Wrap is that I not only get cursors in the beginning of each actual line, but in the beginning of every line as it is displayed at the moment in the editor.

For example, for the following document:

```
1 This is the first line.
2 Second line.
```

It might be wrapped like this:

```
1 This is the first 
  line.
2 Second line.
```

So if I use the method above and add `%` I would get:

```
1 %This is the first 
  %line.
2 %Second line.
```

But what I want is the following:

```
1 %This is the first 
  line.
2 %Second line.
```

Otherwise, I have a `%` in the middle of the line, just because I resized the editor window.

At the moment, I actually turn off Word Wrap to achieve this, but I hope there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update [v1.62](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_62#_thank-you:%7E:text=InsertCursorAbove/Below)+ (October 2021)

This is now natively available in VSCode thanks to [this PR on changing the default behavior of InsertCursorAbove/Below](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/135805). However, it's not enabled by default.

You'll need to update your keybindings to pass in an `args` like this:

```json
{
  "key": "shift+alt+down",
  "command": "editor.action.insertCursorBelow",
  "when": "textInputFocus",
  "args": { "logicalLine": true },
},
{
  "key": "shift+alt+up",
  "command": "editor.action.insertCursorAbove",
  "when": "textInputFocus",
  "args": { "logicalLine": true },
},
```

Comment: "However, it's not enabled by default." The PR seems to say otherwise?

Comment: @aleclarson, you still need to pass in args.  Have you tried it by default without my suggestion and seen it working?

Comment: I haven't been able to get it working with/without the specified args. Not sure why

Comment: Make sure you don't already have another shortcut for `editor.action.insertCursorBelow` or something else that uses the same key combo

Answer (score 2):

Follow the next steps:

1. <kbd>`Alt`</kbd>+<kbd>`Shift`</kbd>+<kbd>`i`</kbd> to put a cursor on every selected line
2. <kbd>`Cmd/Ctrl`</kbd>+<kbd>`←`</kbd> to move all cursors to the beginning of the [wrapped] lines
3. <kbd>`Cmd/Ctrl`</kbd>+<kbd>`←`</kbd> (again) to move all cursors to the actual beginning of the [wrapped] lines

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks. Pretty close to what I wanted ;) I guess the arrow left key is the home or Pos1 key. Then it works, but without ctrl, otherwise the cursor jumps to the beginning of the document. Only problem is if one cursor is already in the beginning of a line and other cursors are in the middle of a line. Then pressing home key repeatedly makes the cursors jump between the first letter of the line and the actual first column of that line and since the cursors start in different positions, some are at the first character and others at column 1. Only relevant if the lines are indented.

Comment: Nope, the `←` key is not the `Home` one. [Here you have an image](https://monosnap.com/file/n8xdTAxPOskVDEg78CRyfcleLdDCbi) 

Comment: ok :) but that is just the normal jump over one word instead of one character?

Comment: Sorry, my bad . In MacOS the behaviour of `Cmd`+`←` moves the cursor to the beginning of the current line instead of jumping over one word. You're right, in Windows/Linux it would be `Ctrl`+`home` in order to jump to the beginning of the line

Comment: What you ask in your first comment about jumping to the actual first column instead of the beginning of the text, that's the reason why I suggested to execute 2 times the `Cmd`+`←` shortcut. I don't know if in Windows/Linux it would be the same typing `Ctrl`+`home` two times. Could you confirm me that in order to edit my response and let it be accepted? 

Comment: @JavierCane Using the shortcut two times worked for me on Windows. However, the shortcut appeared to be <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> to move the cursor to the beginning of the current line(s).

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/26393). The [CursorColumnSelectOnTrueLines extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MartinZimmermannApps.CursorColumnSelectOnTrueLines) by Martin Zimmermann provides commands that show the desired behavior, by default mapped to Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Up/Down.